# IOS custom file read

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to read a custom file type. I have a "test.mbt" file, which has different kinds of data, such as text, image, and even mp4. Each file has their address, so I need to designate the offset and length.

I tried to add the mbt type into `plist` like following picture. [image: (Here)]

However,

`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mbt"];`

above path is always nil. What's wrong with this?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you added the file to your Xcode project and to the correct target?

Comment: Yes, it is under the Xcode project. It keeps returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever files that you see under your project at the left side panel not necessarily has been added to your project. You need to check whether your mbt file is inside your target by clicking your project then on right panel, click your Target, goto "**Build Phases**" and under "**Copy Bundle Resources**" and ensure your mbt file is listed there. If not, then you drag it to there. Then it should work.